Grub timeout 0 not loading with Shift
So, I have a Grub dual boot (Linux Mint and Windows 8.1) on timeout=0 (and maybe some other configuration? it's a very old system). I can't edit the Grub config file, do not have any admin rights on my Windows, and I've tried pressing Shift, but it says "GRUB Loading" for a couple seconds then disappears, and then boots up Windows. No idea what causes this, I've tried a lot of combinations including Esc as well, that does nothing. If I could get any help would greatly appreciate :)

Timeout of 0, gives no time to press shift (BIOS) or escape (UEFI) to get a grub menu. Better to have small amount, I use 3 sec, but still have to be quick when I want to get to grub menu, but it auto boots first entry quickly.

You've provided no Ubuntu product & release details; and given the GRUB defaults vary on version (where release of Ubuntu controls this), defaults change and you've not specified what you're using. What Ubuntu are you using?

This answer says In practice, on some EFI systems the SHIFT keypress is not relayed to GRUB due to how the underlying firmware works. In those cases, press SHIFT+non-ASCII character (e.g. SHIFT+F1) before the boot process to get to the GRUB menu. Does the suggestion of SHIFT+F1 work?
